# SARIMAX: incremental Kalman filter

Tags: python, statsmodels, kalman-filter, arima

Could you please let me know if it is possible to use the current statsmodels SARIMAX code to apply Kalman filter incrementally (to make it faster)?

Here is what I mean. Imagine, one fits an SARIMAX model (#1) using data with indices in `[iFitBegin, iFitEnd]`, then one wants to use such a model to make predictions for data with indices in `[iFitEnd+1, iDataEnd]`. To do that in the current code, it seems, one has to create a new SARIMAX model (#2) using data with indices in `[iFitBegin, iDataEnd]` and apply Kalman filter on the model #2 with parameters taken from model #1. After that one can request predictions from model #2. However, it is expensive computationally to do (for large models) if predictions are done on streaming data (**where new data arrives one data point at a time**) since every time one has to redo all Kalman filtering from `iFitBegin` to the index `iPred` (the one, at which a prediction is required). Mathematically, Kalman filter is applied incrementally, i.e. if Kalman filtering is done up to index `iPred`, then to do filtering up to index `iPred+1` one just has to take the state at `iPred` and only apply one step of Kalman filter using a single new data point at `iPred+1`, and so it would be great if one could do it in the code incrementally as well.

Could you please let me know if there is a way to do such incremental Kalman filtering (i.e. one state update at a time) in the current statsmodels SARIMAX implementation?

Answer (score 3):

This is now available in the development version of Statsmodels (i.e. in the master branch of Github) and will be available in version 0.11 (no timeline for that release yet, though).

Basically, you will be able to do the following:

```
training_mod = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(training_endog, order=(1, 0, 0))
training_res = training_mod.fit()

# The `extend` call will only apply the Kalman filter to the
# updated_endog
extended_res = training_res.extend(updated_endog)
fcasts = extended_res.forecast()
```

Note that this will **not** re-estimate the parameters, but it will allow you to extend the current results to accommodate an updated set of observations without having to re-run the Kalman filter over the `training_endog` sample.

See https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html for some additional details.